# Why won't my an element go inline with my navbar?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to create a navbar for a website that I am working on, and it has been working relatively smoothly, except for when I try to add an element to the top of the page with the navbar, but it will be styled to stick out from the navbar (with a different color and size of the box).

```css
#navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #CC0000;
}

#navbar li {
    float: left;
}

#navbar li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#signup-nav{
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#signup-nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'navbar'> 
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fundraising Tips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id = "signup-nav"><a href='#'><h1>SIGN UP</h1></a></div>  <!--This is what I am trying to put inline with the rest of the navbar, but style it slightly differently-->
</div>
```

Comment: I think it's because your navbar is not inline. Not sure what you mean by stick out cause you have navbar overflow set to hidden. So anything sticking out of navbar will be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ul` is a block element so it will take up the full width by default. One of the easiest ways to do this is using `flexbox`. The advantage of [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is that it is very flexible (surprise!) so it is very common for tasks like this.

- If you make your navbar `display:flex`, this will automatically fit all its child elements into the block.
- If you make your ul `flex: 1;` this lets it grow and shrink with the window.
- We don't need to give the signup link any flex value, and it will take as muchspace as it needs.

. For example, you can control if each individual elements grows and/or shrink with the window, make one (or more) a fixed with and let the rest take up the remaining space etc.

FYI for your example, you also need to make some other styling changes such as:

- padding on your signup link
- margin on the h1
- add the background colour to the whole navbar, not just the ul
- remove the `float:right` (no need for it anymore)

see the working example below with all the changes:

```css
#navbar {
  display: flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #CC0000;
}

#navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 1;
}

#navbar li {
  float: left;
}

#navbar li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#signup-nav {
  font-size: 18px;
}

#signup-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 3px 16px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:orange;
  border:2px solid #000;
}

#signup-nav h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='navbar'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fundraising Tips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="signup-nav">
    <a href='#'>
      <h1>SIGN UP</h1>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!--This is what I am trying to put inline with the rest of the navbar, but style it slightly differently-->
</div>
```

Comment: @Spaceball did this work for you, or do you need more help with it?

Comment: Yes, it did! Is this part of the CSS library which I was unaware of? Also, on a second note, if I want to get rid of the red behind the word sign up and create an orange box instead, would this be possible?

Comment: @Spaceball To make the background of "Sign Up" orange, you just need to change the CSS for `#signup-nav a` to add `background:orange` (or whatever colour you want).

Comment: I see, thank you. And I assume this goes with other properties as well? (such as, giving signup a border/ making the border larger, etc.) I am trying to make a dynamic looking navbar, with "sign up" standing out.

Comment: @Spaceball Yes, you can style the link element with borders, colours, font size etc using that CSS rule!

Comment: @Spaceball I've edited my answer to show the background and border, you can make any other changes to the same rule. FYI if you are interested in finding out more about flexbox, you can see the [support for flexbox here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). There is lots of info out there if you want to learn more, to start you could take a look at [A guide to Flexbox - CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this, and this isn't necessarily the best way, but it is one way. You could use a [flex container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) and the `justify-content` property to position the elements.

If you set `justify-content` to `space-between`, this will distribute items evenly. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content):

> The items are evenly distributed within the alignment container along
> the main axis. The spacing between each pair of adjacent items is the
> same. The first item is flush with the main-start edge, and the last
> item is flush with the main-end edge.

Example:

```css
#navbar {
  display: flex;  /* added */
  justify-content: space-between;  /* added */
  background-color: #CC0000;  /* added */
}

#navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* background-color: #CC0000; */ /* removed */
}

#navbar li {
  float: left;
}

#navbar li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#signup-nav {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#signup-nav h1 {
  margin: 0;  /* added */
}

#signup-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='navbar'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fundraising Tips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="signup-nav"><a href='#'>
      <h1>SIGN UP</h1>
    </a></div>
  <!--This is what I am trying to put inline with the rest of the navbar, but style it slightly differently-->
</div>
```